# Windows - network file transfer consumes storage - lacks housekeeping?

Tags: networking, storage, cache

Using Windows 11 to transfer between 2 network locations (both NAS), I'm finding tens of GB of storage persists in being used up on the PC doing the transfer. It's not visible in any temp locations I can find. It gets so bad it fills up the drive. I'm surprised there's no automatic housekeeping, especially from storage sense when the drive is nearly full.

[Example: move 20GB of files, 20GB of hard drive space on the intermediate computer remains "used". Subsequent copies add to this cumulatively until the drive is full.]

From storage settings, clearing temporary files *does* resolve the issue. That's far from ideal, obviously. I'd like to understand what's happening though. The space in question isn't a good fit for any of the subcategories one can choose to clean (there's nothing like "caches"), and significantly the quantity of space involved isn't included in the amount it claims it is cleaning. For example, it can be so wrong that it says it's cleaning 100MB when in fact it's cleaning 50GB.

I've not yet left the disc filled for a long period to see if *periodic* storage sense (as opposed to drive-full storage sense) does eventually clean it up. I expect it will, since the manual clean does that. But surely it should be cleaned as soon as the transfer operation is concluded. **Is anyone aware of any settings that could influence this?** Note that I don't have any kind of "turn off caching on this drive" setting since they are network locations.

In case it's relevant, the source NAS is an odd arrangement, it's a WD running Twonky because that's the most straightforward way to convert metadata into filenames. The destination is a QNAP NAS mapped to a drive letter.

Comment: Are you copying the files with Windows Explorer?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I have to because of the Twonky requirement. As far as I can establish there is no command-line interface to it. The issue here is that the filenames are all basically uninformative, and I need the metadata extracted, which is exactly what Twonky's GUI via Explorer can do.

Comment: The computer you initiate the transfer from WILL cache the copied data, because it is essentially performing two copies: one from the target to itself, and another from itself to the destination. Being able to clean this up more automatically is a viable goal, but the way to fix this is to initiate the move from one of the involved devices, likely via some form of remote access (SSH, RDP, etc).

Comment: I don't know the feature set, but I'd guess QNAP has some sort of remote shell that can do this. I'd be surprised if Twonky doesn't have a similar ability.